# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Xcode 13 react native

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

The ios build works fine in ios versions 15 and 14 but crashes in **ios 13**

Here is crash log:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR
> Referenced from: /Users/mobiledeveloper1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A984B2B1-76D2-4952-86D9-A0B965E44A96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/50FCF1BC-C2BF-4422-8D9F-D20909AD82FA/xxxx.app/xxxx
> Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
> in /Users/mobiledeveloper1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A984B2B1-76D2-4952-86D9-A0B965E44A96/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/50FCF1BC-C2BF-4422-8D9F-D20909AD82FA/xxxx.app/xxxx
> dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
> DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/mobiledeveloper1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-cjvgiueyhtqsdwfeubkhymexnxwg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
> DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.0.simrunt

Comment: You seem to call at some point https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctradioaccesstechnologynr which is only available in iOS14.1+ and not in iOS13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the version of the @react-native-community/netinfo npm package. Now it works fine. Thanks for ur response [@larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) and [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4543645/boris-nikolic)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test CoreTelephony.framework on a Simulator. You can't make calls from Simulator.